# Google Glass: Can't swipe between cards in immersion

Tags: java, android, google-glass

My problem is I've created an immersion activity with several cards in it. When I try and swipe between the cards, nothing happens. I can swipe down to end the activity, but I can't swipe between cards. The funny thing is if I let the glass go to sleep and then wake it up again, I can then swipe between cards. Because of this oddity, I'm pretty sure I'm missing one line of code that gives the cards focus or something, but I don't know what it is.

I've found a workaround using a gesture detector,  but it doesn't look like normal swiping, so I'd like to avoid that. My code is below:

```
package com.akqa.glass.recipie;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.glass.media.Sounds;
import com.google.android.glass.view.WindowUtils;
import com.google.android.glass.widget.CardBuilder;
import com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollAdapter;
import com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by torti_000 on 11/29/2014.
 */
public class PairingsActivity extends Activity {

    private CardAdapter mAdapter;
    private CardScrollView mCardScroller;

    private int mTapPosition;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private boolean mVoiceMenuEnabled = true;
    private String ingredientUrl = null;
    private static final String TAG = "Ingredients";
    private static final String URL_BASE = "http://www.ingredientpairings.com/?i=";
    private ArrayList<String> iList;
    //Number of ingredients to display per card.
    private static final int ITEMS_PER_CARD = 4;
    private int numCards;
    String object = null;
    Context context;
    private View mView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        //Loading
        mView = buildView();
        mCardScroller = new CardScrollView(this);
        mCardScroller.setAdapter(new CardScrollAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return mView;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                return mView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getPosition(Object item) {
                if (mView.equals(item)) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION;
            }
        });
        setContentView(mCardScroller);
        Log.d(TAG, "View has been set");
        mCardScroller.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Plays sound.
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.playSoundEffect(Sounds.TAP);
            }
        });
        //Recipes
        iList = new ArrayList<String>();
        context = this;
        Intent pairings = getIntent();
        object = pairings.getStringExtra("Object");
        Log.i(TAG, "Pairings thinks object is: " + object);
        new GetIngredients().execute(object);
    }

    /**
     * Create Loding Page
     */
    private View buildView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating Loading Card");
        CardBuilder card = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.TEXT);
        card.setText("Loading");
        return card.getView();
    }

    /**
     * Creates list of cards that showcase different type of {@link com.google.android.glass.widget.CardBuilder} API.
     */
    private List<CardBuilder> createCards(Context context) {
        ArrayList<CardBuilder> cards = new ArrayList<CardBuilder>();
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating Cards");
        /*
         *  One ingredient per card...
         */
        for(int i = 0; i < iList.size(); i++){
            cards.add(new CardBuilder(context, CardBuilder.Layout.TEXT)
                .setText(iList.get(i)));
            Log.d(TAG, "Ingredient is: " + iList.get(i));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Done adding pairings?");
        return cards;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCardScroller.activate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mCardScroller.deactivate();
        super.onPause();
    }

    public class GetIngredients extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                ingredientUrl = object.replaceAll(" ", "+");
                Log.d(TAG, ingredientUrl);
//                strings[0].replaceAll(" ", "+");
                Log.d(TAG, "Finding matches for " + object);
                Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(URL_BASE + ingredientUrl).get();
                Log.d(TAG, "Matches found for " + object);
                Elements ingredients = doc.select("div.main  p b");
//                Log.d(TAG, "Ingredients are: " + ingredients.toString());
                for (Element ingredient : ingredients) {
                    String data = ingredient.text();
                    iList.add(data);
                    buffer.append("Data [" + data + "] \r\n");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ingredient is: " + data);
                }
            }
            catch(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            // Compute the number of cards needed to display the items with 4 per card (rounding up to
            // capture the remainder).
            numCards = (int) Math.ceil((double) iList.size() / ITEMS_PER_CARD);
            startCards();
        }
    }
    private void startCards(){
        mAdapter = new CardAdapter(createCards(this));
//        mCardScroller = new CardScrollView(this);
        mCardScroller.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        setContentView(mCardScroller);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onCreate(), add this line before the setContentView() like this:

```
mCardScroller.activate();   //add this line
setContentView(mCardScroller);
```

You had this line in your onResume() and that's why it is behaving as is.

Comment: As a note to anybody with an issue extremely similar to mine, make sure you're using different cardscrollviews for your cardscrolladapters, otherwise the activating won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I was switching the content view between a CardScrollView and a SurfaceView. After I made sure that onPause() and onResume() were both called in the logically correct places, the scroller was fine.

It seems like if the CardScrollView has lost focus then the scroller loses functionality and calling .activate() only works if .deactivate() has been called beforehand, hence why both onPause() and onResume() need to both be called in the logically correct places as .deactivate() is called within onPause() and .activate() is called within onResume(). I tried just calling .deactivate() and .activate() on their own instead of onPause() and onResume() and the behaviour was the same in both instances, supporting what I have written here.

So, in short, if switching between views with setContentView(), be sure to call onPause() before the switch and onResume() after the switch otherwise the scroller will stop responding.